# How to pool variables that rarely occur, particularly with respect to survey data

Tags: survey, dimensionality-reduction, correspondence-analysis

From the text : *Multiple Correspondents Analysis* by *Brigette LeRoux*

> very infrequent categories of active variables need to be pooled with
>   others when feasible

The text doesn't explain how this should be done, and I'm finding it hard to find literature / examples of this being done.

For example, if I have variables `x1,x2` as follows

```
x1 = [1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0]
x2 = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
x3 = [0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1]
```

Then I might want to pool `x2`, but how would I go about doing that?

## Edit

"other". So, if you surveyed people about their favorite colors and 45 % said "pink" and 45% said "blue" and you had many other answers that were infrequent, you might pool the rest into "other". – Sal Mangiafico 41 mins ago

Following an example from @SalMangiafico in the [comments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/432292/how-to-pool-variables-that-rarely-occur-particularly-with-respect-to-survey-dat?noredirect=1#comment806467_432292):

Suppose that I have two variables `pink (p)` and `fuchsia (f)` as follows

```
p = [1, 1, 1, 0]
f = [1, 0, 0, 1]
```

How would they be combined? Would be be using an `or` operation such as

```
p or f = [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

or are there other ways to approach this?

Comment: A case I can think of where that makes sense is if you can reasonably pool a set of dichotomous variables into one called "other". So, if you surveyed people about their favorite colors and 45 % said "pink" and 45% said "blue" and you had many other answers that were infrequent, you might pool the rest into "other".

Comment: @SalMangiafico thanks, that makes sense. In this case it is a grouping of a category within a variable though (that variable being colour) rather than a grouping of a variable itself? In the post I'm talking about grouping a variable not just categories within it. Are you aware of any literature around this topic?

Comment: Although, reviewing the quote, the author is referring to categories of a variable rather than the variable themselves. In this case, if there is a binary variable which has a very infrequent positive response, what would be done? (or nothing?)

Comment: The case of having a single infrequent independent dichotomous variable.  One possibility is to combine it with another one.  "Fuchsia" is close enough to "pink" for them to be combined.  Another is to exclude it.  If it's so rare, it's unlikely to provide reliable information to the model, so just exclude it. A third is to leave it in the model as it is.  But then you have to be sure that it isn't exerting undue influence on the model.  That is, that your conclusions aren't be swayed by a few rare observations.

Comment: @SalMangiafico thanks, I have added that as an example to the question, though how to go about combining the colours in this case still isn't clear to me.

Comment: Assuming a value of 1 is "true" or "yes" then you could combine variables with addition or Boolean OR.  Be careful that your data are coded the way you think they are.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a concrete example.

Let's say I survey people on a happiness index.  And in the survey I also ask for their favorite color.  I want to see if their favorite color can predict happiness.  I use dummy coding for the favorite color variables.

Here, most people answer "Pink" or "Blue", but there are also rare answers of "Fuchsia" and "Black"

(The following code can be run in R or at https://rdrr.io/snippets/ ).

```
Happiness = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 14, 20, 25, 30, 32, 100, 20)
Pink     = c( 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,   1,  1,  1,  1,  1,   0,  0)
Blue     = c( 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,   0,  0)
Fuchsia  = c( 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,   0,  1)
Black    = c( 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,   1,  0)

Data = data.frame(Happiness, Pink, Blue, Fuchsia, Black)
```

Option 1:  Ignore rare colors.

Here, I'll ignore both Fuchsia and Black.  I will make a new data set with these observations totally excluded so that they are not combined by the software with either Pink or Blue.

```
Data1 = Data[Data$Pink==1 | Data$Blue ==1,]

model1 = lm(Happiness ~ Pink, data=Data1)

summary(model1)

   ### beta = 12.0, p = 0.008, r-squared = 0.609
```

Option 2: Combine rare variables.

Another option is to combine rare values either with other rare values or with a common value that is relevantly similar.  For example, we could combine Fuchsia and Black into a variable "other".

Instead, in this case, let's say Fuchsia is close enough to Pink to combine them into one variable.

Note here that the data are dummy coded as 0 (false) and 1 (true), so that it makes sense to use addition to combine them (1 + 0 = 1; 0 + 1 = 1; 0 + 0 = 0).  If the values were TRUE and FALSE, we could use the Boolean operator OR to combine them (TRUE | FALSE = TRUE, FALSE | TRUE = TRUE, FALSE | FALSE =FALSE).

Also note that it's important to be sure that the values are coded in the way you expect.  Here, I'm treating 1 as TRUE, but if the data were coded where 1 were FALSE, I would use a different operation to combine the variables.

```
Data$PinkFuchsia = Data$Pink + Data$Fuchsia

Data$PinkFuchsia

   ### [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
```

Because the Happiness value for the Fuchsia observation isn't terribly different than those for Pink, the model doesn't change much, and we can feel relatively justified in combining these variables.

```
Data2 = Data[Data$PinkFuchsia==1 | Data$Blue ==1,]

model2 = lm(Happiness ~ PinkFuchsia, data=Data2)

summary(model2)

   ### beta = 11.3, p = 0.006, r-squared = 0.586
```

Option 3:  Include the rare Black variable as it is.

```
Data3 = Data[Data$Pink==1 | Data$Blue==1 | Data$Black==1 ,]
```

But note here that including the one Black observation changes the model greatly. We would want to be cautious here.  Are we allowing a single (or rare) observation to matter too much in our results? Because the values are rare, it's difficult to know how to answer this question, and we might want to avoid this approach.

```
model3 = lm(Happiness ~ Pink + Black, data=Data3)

summary(model3)

   ### For Black, beta = 87.8, p = < 0.0001. r-squared for model = 0.965
```